# What happens when you send an 8bit number to an output which is 4bit? C Language

Tags: hardware, io, 8-bit

I'm studying in high school, and we have an electronics project.

We have an output from our computer which is 4 bit, output address is `37Ah`
and my teacher did this:

```
outportb(0x37A,0x80);
```

so what will appear in the output? 0h or 8h?

Comment: We need more information. What are you using? Some sort of micro-controller? Where is outportb defined? Most likely only 4 bits will go through and 4 will be lost, but that's up to outportb. It could also cut 8 bit number into 2 4 bit numbers and then send them. I've seen some displays work this way.

Comment: outportb is from dos.h
We don't have any special outportb function.

Comment: And where did you get dos.h from? It's not a standard C header. What are you using to develop software?

Answer (score 1):

You need to explain your problem a little better. What microprocesser do you use etc. Is it a 4-port output you have?

But 0x80 is equal to:
0b1000000 and if you use the lower 4 bits: 0b1000xxxx, then they will be zero (not turned on). This will happen if 0x37A is 8bit.

Otherwise, explain your problem better :)

Can't you try and see what happens? or is it only theoretical until now?

**EDIT:**

I see it is a printer port. Check http://www.tinet.cat/~sag/gifs/ParallelPort.gif if you use port 2,3,4,5 then the upper 4 bits really doesn't matter :) as said in my comment.

Comment: Ok hmm, It's for an electronics project.
Our computers at school run pentium 4 or 3 I think,they're kinda old.

But we have an output which is only 4bits from the computer, and we connect it to our electronics project.
but here the teachers sends a 8bit data to a 4bit output,
so I don't understand what happens - only the 4 lower bits are going out or all of them( cut the number to 2 4bit numbers)?

Comment: The 'Y' in 0xY0 will properly be discarded because you only need the lower 4 bits. But again, it depends on several things. It could also use the upper 4 bits. But the lower 4 bits is what I would bet on ;)

Comment: It's not directly related to computers you are using. What you seem to be doing is called bit-banging. You are using standard hardware to create special  output. The point is how software processes your output.

Answer (score 1):

Unless this is a 4-bit CPU from the 70s then your output port will be **8** bits, but the connected hardware might only use 4. In that case it is common (but not necessary) to use the lower 4 bits so you would have 0x0 as value. But that makes using 0x80 a smokescreen, it would be the same as 0x00 and 0xF0. So from that alone I would guess that the upper 4 bits are used here, and the value sent is 0x8.

But a twisted hardware engineer could have used the middle 4 bits.

Comment: It's like a printer output from the old computers
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fa/Parallel_computer_printer_port.jpg

like this,
and we take out the 1,14,16,17 as Output address 37A.